# Bootstrap datepicker passing to c# ajax call

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, datatables, asp.net-ajax

I am having difficulty passing a date to ajax call. The date is from a bootstrap datetimepicker. I do get the value javascript side by using:

```
 var DateFrom = $("#dpDateFrom").data('datepicker').date;
```

I pass this date via ajax call from a datatable.

```
 tblActivity = $('#tblActivity').dataTable({
    "oLanguage": { "sEmptyTable": "No data to display" },
    "bJQueryUI": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "sAjaxSource": '/api/activitylogapi/Activityt',
    "aaData": mainJson.aaData,
    "bProcessing": false,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bSort": true,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bRetrieve": true,
    "aoColumns": [
                 { "sTitle": "Activity Type", "mDataProp": "Type", "sWidth": "10%" },
                 { "sTitle": "Comments", "mDataProp": "Comments", "sWidth": "10%" },
                 { "sTitle": "Company Name", "mDataProp": "CompanyName", "sWidth": "10%" },
                 { "sTitle": "Contact", "mDataProp": "Contact", "sWidth": "10%" },
                 { "sTitle": "User", "mDataProp": "UserFullName", "sClass": "truncate", "sWidth": "10%" },
                 { "sTitle": "Created", "mDataProp": "DateS", "sClass": "text-right", "sWidth": "10%" },

    ],
    "iDeferLoading": [mainJson.count, mainJson.count],
    "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [1,2,3,5] }],
    "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {
        aoData.push({ "name": "DateFrom", "value": DateFrom });
        aoData.push({ "name": "DateTill", "value": DateTill });

        doDataTablePostAjaxCalling(this, sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings);
    },
    "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {            
    }
```

My ajax call is expecting a DateTimeOffset but can not get the date to pass through succesfully. Is there a way I must fomrat my javascript date

Comment: What value does `DateFrom` have when it hits the server?

Comment: I fixed this by just getting value as a string with .val() then in javascript creating a date object. Then passing that as date to my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by getting the value from datepicker with .val(). Then creating a date object in javascript then passing that to my controller.